# Querying values from a Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula

I have a table of foods with their nutritional values in a Google Sheets. My objective is to enter portions consumed of each food in a given day and calculate nutritional intake for the day. For each row that has a portion entered, I want to summarize the nutritional values times the number of portions served.  I've given a very simplified version below.

Can anyone tell me how to go about doing this in Google Sheets?

```
PORTIONS  FOOD       CALORIES   FAT   PROTEIN
   1      beef       250        34    25
          chicken    220        22    13
          carrots     20        12    23
   2      beans       40        25     5
--------------------------------------------
TOTALS               330        84    35
```

Comment: can you please share a sample spreadsheet - it is easier to give an answer if i can actually play with a little dummy data before giving an exact answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C6 place:

```
=sumproduct($A2:$A5,C2:C5)
```

Then copy across to D6 and E6

Comment: Great! If that worked for you, could you please approve the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see now how to do that.  OK, done. Thanks again.